# Why does CodeIgniter store so much data in it's cookie?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com) set to store sessions in the database but still it insists on the following being in a cookie:

```
a:4:{
 s:10:"session_id";s:32:"191668b039f27f1a4fa25586aaaf708e";
 s:10:"ip_address";s:14:"123.12.123.123";
 s:10:"user_agent";s:50:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko";
 s:13:"last_activity";i:1336549698;
}9fed5a2005d9df3ccedff9589aa7d36f
```

All of this is also in the `default_ci_sessions` so I don't know why it's also going in the cookie! I'm asking because of the new EU cookie legislation about the local storage of user identifiable data. I'm not entirely sure this falls under the legislation but the concern has been raised.

Comment: you worry too much. almost every site in the world does this.

Comment: This is nothing to do with PyroCMS, it is how CI does things. Please amend your question and me and @narfbg will discuss this with the other CodeIgniter devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from CodeIgniter Session library's logic (as PyroCMS is built with CI). I currently can't tell you why it's made that way, but I also don't see a need to store such data separately in the cookie itself. I'll open a discussion on that and I'll post the link here to keep track.

Edit: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1344

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is to do with the CI Session class and the preferences you can set.

When the script checks the validity of the cookie, it (may) check the IP address and UA string against the current user agent data from the Input class, regardless of whether you are using the DB sessions or not (in `sess_read()`) to validate the cookie. If you are using the DB it also checks the DB data against the cookie data.

The script does this to prevent against hacking attempts - someone could theoretically guess or sniff the correct session_id, IP address or UA string, but all three would be much harder.

More here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's stored on the local machine, it could all be done on the server and simply store a session id in the cookie, just like native php sessions do

Comment: Yes it does - the script compares both the cookie to the UA details and the DB.

Comment: I don't see the difference between the UA details (etc.) being stored in the session though.

Comment: Yeah, like I said it validates the cookie against the UA details. This is maybe overkill, as you could just do it against the DB, but anything you can do to improve security is probably worth it.

Comment: The information in the cookie is the same as that in the database. The UA details might as well be compared to those in the database rather than having it all in the cookie too.